# Why is the output always the same when I try to solve a maze using DFS

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, maze

I'm trying to generate a maze and solve it if possible using DFS algorithm. I start by

generating a random maze then attempt to solve it if there is a solution. The maze is generated

randomly every time the code runs but the path of the generated maze is always the same and it

seems like there is always a path even though the maze is generated randomly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>

const int SIZE = 10;

enum Direction {
    TOP,
    RIGHT,
    BOTTOM,
    LEFT
};

struct Cell {
    bool visited;
    bool walls[4];  // top, right, bottom, left

    Cell() {
        visited = false;
        std::fill(walls, walls + 4, true);
    }
};

int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(min, max);
    return dis(gen);
}


bool isValidCell(int row, int col) {
    return (row >= 0 && row < SIZE && col >= 0 && col < SIZE);
}

void removeWall(Cell& current, Cell& next, Direction direction) {
    current.walls[direction] = false;

    if (direction == TOP)
        next.walls[BOTTOM] = false;
    else if (direction == RIGHT)
        next.walls[LEFT] = false;
    else if (direction == BOTTOM)
        next.walls[TOP] = false;
    else if (direction == LEFT)
        next.walls[RIGHT] = false;
}

void generateMaze(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& maze, int row, int col) {
    static const int dx[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};  // right, down, left, up
    static const int dy[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};

    maze[row][col].visited = true;

    std::vector<int> directions = {TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT};
    std::shuffle(directions.begin(), directions.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));

    for (int direction : directions) {
        int newRow = row + dy[direction];
        int newCol = col + dx[direction];

        if (isValidCell(newRow, newCol) && !maze[newRow][newCol].visited) {
            removeWall(maze[row][col], maze[newRow][newCol], static_cast<Direction>(direction));
            generateMaze(maze, newRow, newCol);
        }
    }
}

void generateMaze(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& maze) {
    generateMaze(maze, 0, 0);
}

void displayMaze(const std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& maze) {
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; ++col) {
            std::cout << "+";
            std::cout << (maze[row][col].walls[TOP] ? "---" : "   ");
        }
        std::cout << "+\n";

        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; ++col) {
            std::cout << (maze[row][col].walls[LEFT] ? "|" : " ");
            std::cout << "   ";
        }
        std::cout << "|\n";
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; ++col) {
        std::cout << "+---";
    }
    std::cout << "+\n";
}

bool solveMazeDFS(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& maze, int row, int col, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& path) {
    static const int dx[] = {0, 1, 0, -1}; // right, down, left, up
    static const int dy[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
    if (!isValidCell(row, col) || maze[row][col].visited)
        return false;

    maze[row][col].visited = true;

    if (row == SIZE - 1 && col == SIZE - 1) {
        // Reached the end of the maze
        path.push_back(std::make_pair(row, col));
        return true;
    }

    for (int direction = 0; direction < 4; ++direction) {
        int newRow = row + dy[direction];
        int newCol = col + dx[direction];

        if (solveMazeDFS(maze, newRow, newCol, path)) {
            // Found a valid path, add the current cell to the path
            path.push_back(std::make_pair(row, col));
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool solveMaze(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& maze, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& path) {
    // Reset the visited flag of cells in the maze
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            maze[i][j].visited = false;
        }
    }

    // Start solving the maze from the beginning
    return solveMazeDFS(maze, 0, 0, path);
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> maze(SIZE, std::vector<Cell>(SIZE));
    generateMaze(maze);
    displayMaze(maze);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> path;
    if (solveMaze(maze, path)) {
        std::cout << "Solution:\n";
        for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            std::cout << "(" << path[i].first << ", " << path[i].second << ")";
            if (i > 0)
                std::cout << " -> ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No solution found.\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Example of output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           |                           |
+---+---+   +   +---+---+---+---+---+   +
|       |   |   |                   |   |
+   +---+   +   +   +---+---+---+   +   +
|   |       |               |       |   |
+   +   +---+   +---+---+   +   +---+   +
|   |   |       |       |   |   |       |
+   +   +---+   +   +   +---+   +---+   +
|   |       |   |   |       |       |   |
+   +---+   +---+   +---+   +   +   +   +
|   |       |       |       |   |   |   |
+   +   +---+   +---+   +---+---+   +   +
|       |       |                   |   |
+   +---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+   +
|       |                   |       |   |
+---+   +---+---+   +---+   +---+   +   +
|   |           |   |       |       |   |
+   +---+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+   +
|                       |               |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Solution:
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (0, 3) -> (0, 4) -> (0, 5) -> (0, 6) -> (0, 7) -> (0, 8) -> (0, 9) -> (1, 9) -> (2, 9) -> (3, 9) -> (4, 9) -> (5, 9) -> (6, 9) -> (7, 9) -> (8, 9) -> (9, 9)
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number different numbers thus I get random mazez so the problem is not in the getRandomNumber() function

Comment: yeah, I misread and was confused, sorry for that. THough, before using random numbers you should use a debugger with non-random input. Only when this works as expected you are ready for the next step. What did you see when running this with a debugger attached?

Comment: Try with the most minimal maze possible that replicates the problem (i.e. change the `SIZE`). Then use a debugger to step through the code to see what really happens. It's tedious, especially with recursive functions, but unfortunately it's an integral and important part of programming.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your `solveMazeDFS` code where you are checking to see if a cell is a wall or not. So obviously your code will always find the same path going straight through all the walls.

Comment: `getRandomNumber` should have those local `rd` and `gen` variables be `static`, otherwise it's creating new ones each time and exhausting your system entropy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did and I could not figure out where the problem is. I suspected that the solveMazeDFS is wrong since the maze itself is randomly generated so that part is done. But like I said I got stuck

Comment: @ThisIsMe Yes, `solveMazeDFS` is wrong, it never checks for walls.

Comment: @john oh yeah how stupid I am, it worked thank you. But does it make sense that it always find a path?

Comment: Here is live example: https://godbolt.org/z/scKKhqejs output clearly proves problem is broken DFS, since walls of maze are not respected. I see maze is different each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is always the same because only the outer boundaries are being detected in `solveMazeDFS`. The inner walls are completely ignored. That is why the solution always marches east until it hits the right edge and then south until it hits the bottom.

You could check for a wall and not recurse something like this:

```cpp
        if (not maze[row][col].walls[direction]) {
            if (solveMazeDFS(maze, newRow, newCol, path)) {
                // Found a valid path, add the current cell to the path
                path.push_back(std::make_pair(row, col));
                return true;
            }
        }
```

When run, this produces an actual solution:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |                               |   |
+   +   +---+---+   +---+---+---+   +   +
|   |       |       |           |   |   |
+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+   +   +
|       |       |       |       |   |   |
+---+   +   +---+   +   +---+   +   +   +
|   |   |           |       |   |   |   |
+   +   +   +---+---+---+   +   +   +   +
|       |           |       |   |       |
+   +---+---+---+   +   +---+   +---+   +
|           |       |   |           |   |
+---+---+   +---+---+   +   +---+   +   +
|   |       |       |   |       |   |   |
+   +   +---+   +   +   +   +   +---+   +
|       |       |       |   |   |       |
+   +---+   +---+---+---+   +   +   +---+
|   |       |           |   |   |   |   |
+   +   +---+   +---+   +   +   +   +   +
|       |           |       |           |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Solution:
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) -> (4, 1) -> (4, 0) -> (5, 0) -> (5, 1) -> (5, 2)\
 -> (6, 2) -> (6, 1) -> (7, 1) -> (7, 0) -> (8, 0) -> (9, 0) -> (9, 1) -> (8, 1) -> (8, 2) -> (7\
, 2) -> (7, 3) -> (6, 3) -> (6, 4) -> (7, 4) -> (7, 5) -> (6, 5) -> (5, 5) -> (4, 5) -> (4, 6) -\
> (3, 6) -> (3, 5) -> (2, 5) -> (2, 4) -> (3, 4) -> (3, 3) -> (3, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (1, \
3) -> (1, 4) -> (0, 4) -> (0, 5) -> (0, 6) -> (0, 7) -> (0, 8) -> (1, 8) -> (2, 8) -> (3, 8) -> \
(4, 8) -> (4, 9) -> (5, 9) -> (6, 9) -> (7, 9) -> (7, 8) -> (8, 8) -> (9, 8) -> (9, 9)
```

The generator guarantees the maze always has a path removing walls if necessary.

Comment: I fixed that thank you, is there a way to make sure the maze doesn't have a path sometimes?

Comment: Please next time include example of output. Since as I pointed out in comment problem is obvious when result is seen. I've edited your question to include output.

Comment: You could randomly add a wall to the maze and occasionally that would make it unsolvable. I looked closely at the code that generates the maze and it is not clear to me that it will always produce a solvable maze, but I ran it 1M times and it always found a solution.

Comment: @RandomBits exactly that's why I got confused. thanks anyway

Comment: @ThisIsMe I figured out the generation. It's a DFS of sorts. The initial maze has every wall and generation starts at (0,0). It walks randomly removing walls to clear a path as necessary and makes sure to visit each node exactly once. Thus, there will always be a path from every node to every other node since it visited each node once. Simple, but clever.